# Setting custom pickup location in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing a taxi App

i am able to set the current location to my current location, how to i set it for user to select their own location.at the moment it only picks up my location as current location and i am unable to select new pickup location.

Below is my search screen code

I am developing a taxi App

i am able to set the current location to my current location, how to i set it for user to select their own location.at the moment it only picks up my location as current location and i am unable to select new pickup location.

Below is my search screen code
I am developing a taxi App

i am able to set the current location to my current location, how to i set it for user to select their own location.at the moment it only picks up my location as current location and i am unable to select new pickup location.

Below is my search screen code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:qube_rider_app/AllWidget/progressBox.dart';

import 'package:qube_rider_app/Assistants/requestAssistant.dart';
import 'package:qube_rider_app/DataHandler/appData.dart';
import 'package:qube_rider_app/Models/address.dart';
import 'package:qube_rider_app/Models/placePredictions.dart';
import 'package:qube_rider_app/userMap.dart';


class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen>
{

  TextEditingController pickUpTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController dropOffTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  List<PlacePredictions> placePredictionList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {


    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          new Container(

            height: 190.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("images/mapbg2.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover,),
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  blurRadius: 6.0,
                  spreadRadius: 0.5,
                  offset: Offset(0.7, 0.7),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, top: 30.0, right: 25.0, bottom: 2.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap:()
                        {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Text("Enter Drop of Location", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, fontFamily: "Brand-Regular"),),
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset("images/pickicon.png", height: 20.0, width: 20.0,),

                      SizedBox(width: 18.0),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[300],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                            child: TextField(
                              onChanged: (text)
                              {
                                findPlace(text);
                              },
                              controller: pickUpTextEditingController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "PickUp Location",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400],),
                                fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                                filled: true,
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                isDense: true,
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset("images/desticon.png", height: 20.0, width: 20.0,),

                      SizedBox(width: 18.0),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[300],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                            child: TextField(
                              onChanged: (val)
                              {
                                findPlace(val);
                              },
                              controller: dropOffTextEditingController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Where to",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400],),
                                fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                                filled: true,
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                isDense: true,
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),

          ),

          //tile for predictions
          SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
          (placePredictionList.length > 0)
              ? Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 10.0),
            child: ListView.separated(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, index)
              {
                return PredictionTile(placePredictions: placePredictionList[index],);
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
              itemCount: placePredictionList.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            ),

          )
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void findPlace(String placeName) async
  {
    if(placeName.length > 2)
    {
      String autoCompleteUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$placeName&key=$mapkey&sessiontoken=1234567890&components=country:za";

      var res = await RequestAssistant.getRequest(autoCompleteUrl);

      if(res == "failed")
      {
        return;
      }
      if(res["status"] == "OK")
      {
        var predictions = res["predictions"];

        var placesList = (predictions as List).map((e) => PlacePredictions.fromJson(e)).toList();
        setState(() {
          placePredictionList = placesList;
        });
      }
    }

  }
}

class PredictionTile extends StatelessWidget
{
  final PlacePredictions placePredictions;

  PredictionTile({Key key, this.placePredictions}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return TextButton(

      onPressed: ()
      {
        getPlaceAddressDetails(placePredictions.place_id, context);
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Column
          (
          children: [
            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
             Row(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.add_location_alt),
                SizedBox(width: 14.0),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(placePredictions.main_text, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),),
                      SizedBox(height: 3.0,),
                      Text(placePredictions.secondary_text, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.grey),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          ],

        ),

      ),
    );
  }

  void getPlaceAddressDetails(String placeId, context) async
  {
    showDialog(
       context: context,
       builder: (BuildContext context) => ProgressBox(message: "Getting drop-off location...",)
    );
    
    String placeDetailsUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=$placeId&key=$mapkey";
    var res = await RequestAssistant.getRequest(placeDetailsUrl);
    
    Navigator.pop(context);
    
    if(res == "failed")
    {
      return;
    }

    if(res["status"] == "OK")
    {
      Address address = Address();
      address.placeName = res["result"]["name"];

      address.latitude = res["result"]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
      address.longitude = res["result"]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];
      Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).updatedropOffLocationAddress(address);
      print("Drop off location Selected ::");
      print(address.placeName);

      Navigator.pop(context, "obtainDirection");
    }
  }
}
```